# Validação de data (testes) com Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, data

Estou tentando fazer uma validação de datas com Python. Meu exercício pede a  validação de meses com 31 dias e ano bissexto.

```
def data_valida(data):
    #Valida data. Recebe uma string no formato dd/mm/aaaa e informa
    #um valor lógico indicando se a data é válida ou não.

    dia, mes, ano = data.split("/")

    meses_31 = ('01', '02', '03', '05', '07', '08', '10', '12')

    if ano > '0001' and '12' <= mes >= '01' and '31' <= dia >= '01':

        if int(ano) % 4 == 0 and mes == '2':
            if dia <= '29':
                return True
            else:
                return False
        elif mes == '2':
            if dia < '29':
                return True
            else:
                return False

        if mes == meses_31 and dia <= '31':
            return True
        elif dia <= '31':
            return False

    else:
        return False
```

Testes:

```
def main():
    print('Valida datas:')
    test(data_valida("01/01/2014"), True)
    test(data_valida("31/01/2014"), True)
    test(data_valida("00/00/0000"), False)
    test(data_valida("30/04/2014"), True)
    test(data_valida("31/04/2014"), False)
    test(data_valida("30/09/2014"), True)
    test(data_valida("31/09/2014"), False)
    test(data_valida("30/06/2014"), True)
    test(data_valida("31/06/2014"), False)
    test(data_valida("30/11/2014"), True)
    test(data_valida("31/11/2014"), False)
    test(data_valida("32/01/2014"), False)
    test(data_valida("01/01/0000"), False)
    test(data_valida("01/13/2014"), False)
    test(data_valida("01/00/2014"), False)
    test(data_valida("29/02/2014"), False)
    test(data_valida("29/02/2016"), True)
```

Já tentei encontrar conteúdo sobre e inclusive o mais próximo que cheguei foi no algoritmo atual. Sempre que chego no ano bissexto eu não consigo arrumar e dessa vez que o código parece ok, está retornando `False` para tudo.

Comment: `if mes == meses_31` não faz muito sentido, acho que o correto aqui é `if mes in meses_31`. Isto porque queremos saber se o `mes` é um dos elementos de `meses_31`, e não se ele é igual à tupla inteira (todos os elementos). A condição abaixo desta (`elif dia <= '31': return False`) também tem um problema na lógica, um dia menor ou igual a 31 pode ser válido sim. Um exemplo é o dia `30/04/2014`. Quer tentar resolver a partir disso que falei?

Comment: E passe as datas (dia, mês e ano) para inteiros. Comparar string com string é diferente de comparar inteiros com inteiros. `'04' >= '02'` retorna `True`, mas `'04' >= '2'` retorna `False`. Quando comparamos strings, o Python pega os valor ASCII dos caracteres para comparar.

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas. Acho que consegui finalizar agora rs. Eu não fiz a conversão para inteiros que você indicou. Anyway, poderia me indicar qual seria a maneira mais 'correta' de fazer a conversão? Vou postar como ficou a baixo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como os valores do dia, mês e ano são numéricos, é melhor transformá-los em números. As comparações que você faz com strings levam em conta a [ordem lexicográfica](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order) ("alfabética") e "funciona" por coincidência. Mas se está lidando com valores numéricos, transforme-os em números (isso facilita inclusive as operações aritméticas para verificar anos bissextos, como veremos adiante).

Para isso, você pode usar [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#map), passando a função [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#int) como parâmetro, assim o resultado do `split` será transformado em números:

```
dia, mes, ano = map(int, data.split('/'))
```

Assim, cada elemento da lista retornada por `split` será passado para a função `int`, que transforma a string em um número.

Em seguida, vi que você só quer datas cujo ano seja maior ou igual a 1, então já coloco essa verificação logo no início, junto com a verificação do mês.

Logo depois, precisamos determinar a quantidade de dias daquele mês e ano, e para isso precisamos saber não só o valor do mês (para saber se ele tem 30 ou 31 dias), mas também se o ano é bissexto, caso o mês seja fevereiro. E a regra do ano bissexto é: o ano deve ser múltiplo de 4, mas caso seja múltiplo de 100, só é bissexto se também for múltiplo de 400 (por isso o ano 2000 é bissexto, mas 1900 não).

*Esta regra de considerar bissextos todos os anos múltiplos de 4 era usada anteriormente no Calendário Juliano, mas atualmente usamos o Calendário Gregoriano, que instituiu a nova regra dos múltiplos de 400 - veja mais informações no [wiki da respectiva tag](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/calend%C3%A1rio-gregoriano/info).*

Tendo o último dia do mês definido, podemos verificar se o dia está dentro desses limites. O código fica assim:

```
def data_valida(data):
    # faz o split e transforma em números
    dia, mes, ano = map(int, data.split('/'))

    # mês ou ano inválido (só considera do ano 1 em diante), retorna False
    if mes < 1 or mes > 12 or ano <= 0:
        return False

    # verifica qual o último dia do mês
    if mes in (1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12):
        ultimo_dia = 31
    elif mes == 2:
        # verifica se é ano bissexto
        if (ano % 4 == 0) and (ano % 100 != 0 or ano % 400 == 0):
            ultimo_dia = 29
        else:
            ultimo_dia = 28
    else:
        ultimo_dia = 30

    # verifica se o dia é válido
    if dia < 1 or dia > ultimo_dia:
        return False

    return True
```

Se quiser, pode também colocar um controle adicional, pois caso a função `data_valida` receba uma string contendo um texto qualquer (`'abc'`), ou números que não estejam no formato "dia/mês/ano" (como por exemplo `"12345"` ou `"1-2-3"`), ocorrerá um [`ValueError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError). Então você pode colocar todo o código dentro de um bloco `try` e retornar `False` caso ocorra o `ValueError`:

```
def data_valida(data):
    try:
        # faz o split e transforma em números
        dia, mes, ano = map(int, data.split('/'))

        # mes ou ano inválido, retorna False
        if mes < 1 or mes > 12 or ano <= 0:
            return False

        # verifica qual o último dia do mês
        if mes in (1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12):
            ultimo_dia = 31
        elif mes == 2:
            if (ano % 4 == 0) and (ano % 100 != 0 or ano % 400 == 0):
                ultimo_dia = 29
            else:
                ultimo_dia = 28
        else:
            ultimo_dia = 30

        # verifica se o dia é válido
        if dia < 1 or dia > ultimo_dia:
            return False

        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

---

Como exercício, é válido tentar implementar a lógica acima. Mas se for para código em produção, prefira usar funções específicas para lidar com datas, como por exemplo o [módulo `datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html):

```
from datetime import datetime

def data_valida(data):
    try:
        datetime.strptime(data, '%d/%m/%Y')
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

O método [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) tenta fazer o *parsing* da string, usando o formato indicado (no caso, `'%d/%m/%Y'`, que significa "dia/mês/ano" - [veja a documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) para mais detalhes sobre este parâmetro). Se a data for inválida, ele lança um `ValueError`.

Answer (score 1):

Passou nos testes agora, segue minha resolução:

```
day, month, year = data.split("/")

months_31 = ('01', '02', '03', '05', '07', '08', '10', '12')

if (year >= '0001') and (month >= '01') and (month <= '12') and (day >= '01') and (day <= '31'):

    if int(year) % 4 == 0 and month == '02':
        if day <= '29':
            return True
        else:
            return False
    elif month == '02':
        if day < '29':
            return True
        else:
            return False

    if month in months_31 and day <= '31' or day <= '30':
        return True
    elif day == '31':
        return False

else:
    return False
```

Poderia me indicar coisas que estou fazendo errado (além de não utilizar inteiros)?

Comment: Ano bissexto é aquele que ocorre a cada quatro anos, exceto anos múltiplos de 100 que não são múltiplos de 400. Então, para saber se o ano é bissexto, a condição seria algo como: `if (ano%4==0 and ano%100!=0 or ano%400==0): print("Ano Bissexto")`.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar a seguinte função:

```py
def validar_data(data):
    """
    A função validar_data efetua a validação de uma data digitada pelo usuário (DD/MM/AAAA).
    :param texto: Data digitada pelo usuário(DD/MM/AAAA)
    :return: False (caso a data seja inválida) e True (caso a data seja válida)
    """
    data_digitada = str(data[6:]+'-'+data[3:5]+'-'+data[0:2])
    while True:
        try:
            verif = date.fromisoformat(data_digitada)
            return True
        except ValueError:
            return False
```